# Getting ERROR: could not open relation with OID 6701547 while performing VACUUM FULL on Postgres 9.2

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

We are facing issue in Postgres database 9.2 on RedHat EL 6.8 with an `ext4` file system. We are getting below error every time whenever we preform `vacuum full or reindex database db_name` operation.

```
RRROR:  could not open relation with OID 6701547
```

After getting above error i executed below query to know about the table. But found zero row.

```
db_name=# select oid,relname from pg_class where oid=6701547;
 oid | relname
-----+---------
(0 rows)
```

In postgres log file we are observing below error.

```
CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "db_name.pg_toast.pg_toast_6406054"

ERROR:  could not open file "base/16384/6406600": No such file or directory

CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "db_name.pg_toast.pg_toast_6406597"

ERROR:  could not open file "base/16384/6407373": No such file or directory**
```

We are googling since last one week but no success. How to resolve this error? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Details about the tables:

```
db_name=# SELECT t.oid AS tableoid, t.relfilenode AS tablenode, t.relname AS tablename,
                 ti.oid AS indexoid, ti.relfilenode AS indexnode, ti.relname AS indexname
          FROM pg_class AS t
             JOIN pg_index AS i ON i.indrelid = t.oid
             JOIN pg_class AS ti ON ti.oid = i.indexrelid
          WHERE t.relname = 'pg_toast_6406054';

 tableoid | tablenode |     tablename    | indexoid | indexnode |       indexname 
----------+-----------+------------------+----------+-----------+------------------------
  6406057 |   6406057 | pg_toast_6406054 |  6406059 |   6406059 | pg_toast_6406054_index
(1 row)
```

Tables the toast tables belong to:

```
db_name=# SELECT oid, relname FROM pg_class
          WHERE oid IN (6406054, 6406597);

     oid | relname 
---------+---------
 6406054 | tb_red1
 6406597 | tb_red2
(2 rows)
```

Below is strace file of backend process:

```
[postgres_admin@bpcpgadmin bin]$ strace -p 15929
Process 15929 attached - interrupt to quit
read(0, "\33", 1)                       = 1
read(0, "[", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "A", 1)                         = 1
write(1, "vacuum full;", 12)            = 12
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(0, "\r", 1)                        = 1
write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x40a453, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3768632900}, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {0x30e1a23f30, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
sendto(3, "Q\0\0\0\21vacuum full;\0", 18, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 18
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLERR}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "E\0\0\0[SERROR\0CXX000\0Mcould not op"..., 16384, 0, NULL, NULL) = 92
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLERR}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(3, "Z\0\0\0\5I", 16384, 0, NULL, NULL) = 6
write(2, "ERROR:  could not open relation "..., 49) = 49
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=52, ws_col=197, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(0, TIOCSWINSZ, {ws_row=52, ws_col=197, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {0x40a453, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x30e1a23f30, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3768632900}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
write(1, "amdb=# ", 7)                  = 7
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(0, "\\", 1)                        = 1
write(1, "\\", 1)                       = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(0, "q", 1)                         = 1
write(1, "q", 1)                        = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(0, "\r", 1)                        = 1
write(1, "\n", 1)                       = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x40a453, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3768632900}, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {0x30e1a23f80, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x3768632900}, {0x30e1a23f30, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3768632900}, 8) = 0
sendto(3, "X\0\0\0\4", 5, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0) = 5
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x3768632900}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
open("/var/home/postgres_admin/.psql_history", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=4667, ...}) = 0
read(3, "show all\1SHOW ALL\1help\1SHOW\1SHOW"..., 4667) = 4667
close(3)                                = 0
open("/var/home/postgres_admin/.psql_history", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0600) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
open("/var/home/postgres_admin/.psql_history", O_WRONLY|O_APPEND) = 3
write(3, "vacuum full;\nvacuum full;\nvacuum"..., 55) = 55
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
Process 15929 detached
```

Below is strace file of backend process:

```
**[postgres_admin@bpcpgadmin bin]$ strace -p 28878 -s 1000 -o /tmp/tracfile1.txt**

recvfrom(10, "Q\0\0\0>vacuum full  tb_red1;\0", 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 63
open("pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.stat", O_RDONLY) = 7
fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=182808, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f44e41e5000
read(7, "\232\274\245\1|\226\231\22\2624\2\0\220\7\0\0\0\0\0\0\\\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\273\3321*4\2\0D\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0Cz#\0\0\0\0\0(\33#\0\0\0\0\0\2\273\243[\0\0\0\0\264j\33[\0\0\0\0\362\233\324\23\0\0\0\0RD\225\0\0\0\0\0\313\331\6\0\0\0\0\0\2211\0\0\0\0\0\0U\311\0\0\0\0\0\\T\211B@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
close(7)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f44e41e5000, 4096)            = 0
sendto(9, "\1\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\353\206\320\25\2624\2\0", 16, 0, NULL, 0) = 16
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 10000}) = 0 (Timeout)
open("pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.stat", O_RDONLY) = 7
fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=182808, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f44e41e5000
read(7, "\232\274\245\1\205-\330\25\2624\2\0\220\7\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
close(7)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f44e41e5000, 4096)            = 0
open("pg_stat_tmp/pgstat.stat", O_RDONLY) = 7
fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=182808, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f44e41e5000
read(7, "\232\274\245\1\205-\330\25\2624\2\0\0\0\0\0\231\241\1\0\0\0\0\0\344\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\7\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\322\261\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\207v\10\0\0\0\0\0\223\264G\21*4\2\0D\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0005{#\0\0\0\0\0\26\34#\0\0\0\0\0\17\311\243[\0\0\0\0\301x\33[\0\0\0\0\177\2\325\23\0\0\0\0\\I\225\0\0\0\0\0\313\331\6\0\0\0\0\0\2211\0\0\0\0\0\0U\311\0\0\0\0\0\0M\223p371@\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0:\360\303\315*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\7\f\0\0000624\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\33\0\\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\177\205\372\314*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
brk(0x2273000)                          = 0x2273000
read(7, "*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0TrK0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0;\3134\325*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t 4096) = 4096
read(7, \0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\350\275\324\314*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\364@0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, \7\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\313m\310\314*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\37H\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T*C\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\7\212\6\323*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\227([\316*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T~A\0\0\0\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\215\36\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0P5Y\315*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\16\v\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\323O\0\0\0\0\0\0\33\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\33\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0!0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0Y0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0TWF\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\341 E\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0TRK\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2356\254\325*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\\%k\0\0\0\0\0\r\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\230uK\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\370\315\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0D\215\1\0\0\0\0\0\2219\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0%w\325\323*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\254N\0\0\0\0\0\0\21\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T \t\0\000263\10\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\347G\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\254\340h\323*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\23E\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\226E\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0^\1t\320*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\335\272\20\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0%\205\17\325*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\352L\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\374\245{\326*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\21J\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\21N\0\0\0\0\0\0\23\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\6"..., 4096) = 4096
mmap(NULL, 135168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f44e4183000
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0|\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\342\230\242\325*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\2\310\2\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, 0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, 0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, \5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0001\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0.\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0e\27\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0>0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0T\10J0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0KS\275\322*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\367J\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0M\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, 0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\215A\0\0\0\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0$\0\0\0\0\0\0\316\244\33\315*4\2"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, 0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0;\23\35\325*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\330B\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0005\0\0\0\0\0\0\0!\0\0000637\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\372G0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\347\377\263\320*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\253L\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\254i%0\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\236\6\315\320*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0TuJ\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, \0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, 0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\321\376\260\316*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0%\307\210\326*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\4Q\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\366\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\376\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
read(7, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\335\316\314*4\2\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0T\224\v\320\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\222\23\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\231\23\0\0\0\0\0\0\225\23\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2584
close(7)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f44e41e5000, 4096)            = 0
open("global/7075562", O_RDWR)          = 7
lseek(7, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 8192
open("base/16384/7084737", O_RDWR)      = 8
lseek(8, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 1769472
brk(0x2299000)                          = 0x2299000
mmap(NULL, 135168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f44e4162000
mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f44e4121000
munmap(0x7f44e4121000, 266240)          = 0
munmap(0x7f44e4162000, 135168)          = 0
munmap(0x7f44e4183000, 135168)          = 0
open("base/16384/7084912", O_RDONLY)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("base/16384", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=786432, ...}) = 0
open("base/16384/7084912", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 11
open("base/16384/7084796_fsm", O_RDWR)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("base/16384/7084796", O_RDWR)      = 12
lseek(12, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 1884160
open("base/16384/7075589_fsm", O_RDWR)  = 13
lseek(13, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 24576
open("base/16384/7075589", O_RDWR)      = 14
lseek(14, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 2949120
open("base/16384/7084737_fsm", O_RDWR)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lseek(8, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 1769472
open("base/16384/7075471_fsm", O_RDWR)  = 15
lseek(15, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 24576
open("base/16384/7075471", O_RDWR)      = 16
lseek(16, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 15302656
lseek(16, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 15302656
kill(28149, SIGUSR1)                    = 0
write(16, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
close(11)                               = 0
open("base/16384/7084915", O_RDONLY)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("base/16384", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=786432, ...}) = 0
open("base/16384/7084915", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 11
close(11)                               = 0
open("base/16384/7084917", O_RDONLY)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("base/16384", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=786432, ...}) = 0
open("base/16384/7084917", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 11
open("base/16384/7075790_fsm", O_RDWR)  = 17
lseek(17, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 24576
open("base/16384/7075790", O_RDWR)      = 18
lseek(18, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 1146880
close(11)                               = 0
open("base/16384/7084917", O_RDWR)      = 11
lseek(11, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 0
open("base/16384/7084915", O_RDWR)      = 19
lseek(19, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 0
write(11, "R+\0\0\220\34\26&\1\0\0\0000\0\360\37\360\37\4 \0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
lseek(11, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 8192
fsync(11)                               = 0
lseek(19, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 0
open("base/16384/7084915_vm", O_RDWR)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lseek(11, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 8192
close(19)                               = 0
close(11)                               = 0
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={0, 12998}, ru_stime={0, 7998}, ...}) = 0
open("base/16384/7084912", O_RDWR)      = 11
lseek(11, 0, SEEK_END)                  = 0
open("base/16384/6406054", O_RDWR)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
write(2, "\0\0\322\0\316p\0\0t[ 2019-09-04 05:17:08.784 GMT ]:ERROR:  could not open file \"base/16384/6406054\": No such file or directory\n[ 2019-09-04 05:17:08.784 GMT ]:STATEMENT:  vacuum full  tb_red1;\n", 219) = 219
sendto(10, "E\0\0\0kSERROR\0C58P01\0Mcould not open file \"base/16384/6406054\": No such file or directory\0Fmd.c\0L579\0Rmdopen\0\0", 108, 0, NULL, 0) = 108
kill(28150, SIGUSR1)                    = 0
close(11)                               = 0
open("base/16384/7084917", O_RDWR)      = 11
ftruncate(11, 0)                        = 0
close(11)                               = 0
unlink("base/16384/7084917.1")          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
unlink("base/16384/7084917_fsm")        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
unlink("base/16384/7084917_vm")         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
unlink("base/16384/7084917_init")       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("base/16384/7084915", O_RDWR)      = 11
ftruncate(11, 0)                        = 0
close(11)                               = 0
unlink("base/16384/7084915.1")          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
unlink("base/16384/7084915_fsm")        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
unlink("base/16384/7084915_vm")         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
unlink("base/16384/7084915_init")       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("base/16384/7084912", O_RDWR)      = 11
ftruncate(11, 0)                        = 0
close(11)                               = 0
unlink("base/16384/7084912.1")          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
unlink("base/16384/7084912_fsm")        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
unlink("base/16384/7084912_vm")         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
unlink("base/16384/7084912_init")       = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
sendto(9, "\2\0\0\0\320\3\0\0\0@\0\0\t\976, 0, NULL, 0) = 976
sendto(9, "\2\0\0\0`\1\0\0\0@\0\0\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0q\n352, 0, NULL, 0) = 352
sendto(9, "\2\0\0\0`0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 352, 0, NULL, 0) = 352
sendto(10, "Z\0\0\0\5I", 6, 0, NULL, 0) = 6
recvfrom(10, "X\0\0\0\4", 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 5
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

This is the information about the missing file:

```
amdb=# SELECT relname, relnamespace FROM pg_class WHERE relfilenode = 6406054;

 relname | relnamespace
---------+--------------
 tb_red1 | 2200
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hi 
We have checked our database filesystem state using below command:



[root@hostname ~]# dumpe2fs /dev/mapper/vg01-lv_me | grep -i state

dumpe2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)

Filesystem state:         clean

As shown in output FS is in clean state.

Comment: I guess you get the same error messages when you explicitly run `VACUUM (FULL) pg_toast.pg_toast_6406054;`, right? I guess it is time to restore your database from a backup. And upgrade to a supported release.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that means that the file that contains the data for the table is gone.

If you have no backup, there is no way to recover your data.

You'll have to drop the table.

You should find out what caused the problem. Typically it is one of:

- hardware problem: That could cause data corruption, and a filesystem check may have got rid of the file.

  Is there anything in the `lost+found` subdirectory of the filesystem?
- software bug: I have not heard of a PostgreSQL bug that would actually remove a data file, but who knows. You are running a rather old and unsupported version.
- manual intervention: somebody may accidentally have deleted the file